# rpmbuild creating some extra script in the tmp file

Tags: linux, bash, rpmbuild

I am building rpm in RHEL-6 using rpmbuild command as

`rpmbuild -bb rpm.spec`

This command creates a temporary script which it executes while making rpm. Now the issue is that rpmbuild is creating some extra section in this tmp file which is causing rpm creation to fail. This extra section is mentioned neither in the build script of rpm nor in the rpm.spec file. I am not sure why this is happening. Can someone please suggest me what I might be missing?

Comment: could you give (the usefull part of) the output? Your description is rather vague...

Comment: In the tmp file I am having this section extra which deletes a dir and hence I get an error of No such file of directory
```
[ "$RPM_BUILD_ROOT" != "/" ] && rm -rf "${RPM_BUILD_ROOT}"
    mkdir -p `dirname "$RPM_BUILD_ROOT"`
    mkdir "$RPM_BUILD_ROOT"
```

Comment: Those temporary scripts are the scriptlets, like `%build`, `%install`, etc. To see where it is failing, you can add `set -x` to the beginning. That *should* show you every command before it executes.